# Derived class dependent function

Tags: c++, class, oop, design-patterns

I have base class `DataProcessor`. It is base class for calculators of  position in some coordinate system. So, for example, it can have descendants like: `SphericDataProcessor`, `CartesianDataProcessor`. There is base class `CookedDataCatalogue`, which is base class for containers of some objects' positions. So every `DataProcessor` should be able put its data to every `CookedDataCatalogue`. I can imagine something like this:

```
class CookedDataCatalogue
{
    virtual void Transform(DataProcessor* dp) = 0;

    virtual void PutData(???) = 0;
}


class CookedDataCatalogue1 : public CookedDataCatalogue
{
    void Transform(DataProcessor* dp) override
    {
        dp->TransformTo(this);
    }
}

class CookedDataCatalogue2 : public CookedDataCatalogue
{
    ...
}

class CookedDataCatalogue3 ...

class DataProcessor
{
    virtual void Process() = 0;

    virtual void TransformTo(CookedDataCatalogue1* c) = 0;
    virtual void TransformTo(CookedDataCatalogue2* c) = 0;
    virtual void TransformTo(CookedDataCatalogue3* c) = 0;
}
```

But I don't like it. First of all `void Transform(DataProcessor*)` migrates from base class to all children**. Second, if I build it as library, other user can not add his own `CookedDataUserCatalogue`, because he can't add another `void TransformTo(CookedDataUserCatalogue)`. Third, I don't know how to write function `PutData()`, because every Catalogue uses his own data to contain. Should it be templated?

What is a solution? Is there any programming pattern that I missed?

Comment: Search for "double dispatch pattern c++" on the web.

Comment: Am I getting it wrong: Isn't the cooked superfluous!? You only need a `DataProcessorInterface`

Comment: Catalogues could be provided by someone else, and DataProcessor could not only put data, but search in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this as well as the Double Dispatch Pattern mentioned in the comments:

**Baseline**

The first is that you specify a "baseline" set of co-ordinates. In order to convert first you transform to the core set and then you transform from that.

Advantages: You only need to write a `toBaseline` and `fromBaseline` for any number of different `DataProcessor`s. Adding a new `DataProcessor` is as simple as creating it and then writing the transformation to and from the core set.

Disadvantages: Performance will suffer as you do two transformations in most cases. Accuracy may suffer due to losses either in representation or conversion.

**Transformer objects**

Create an interface that converts an object from `DataProcessor` to `DataProcessor`.

Create an instance of that interface for each supported transformation.

Have a utility class that has a map of source and destination pairs to the correct transform to use. Call a method on that utility class to perform the transformation on demand.

Advantages: No wastage from having to do multiple transformations.

Disadvantages: n^2 `Transform` objects need creating where n is the number of different `DataProcessor` objects. When creating a new `DataProcessor` you will need to write and add `Transform` objects for each `DataProcessor` added. Missing `Transform`s will be detected at run time not compile time.